# Converter data brasileira para americana para fazer o parser para um objeto Date

Tags: data, dart, flutter

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que lê uma página html e obtém algumas informações, entre elas uma data. Esta data está em português, no seguinte formato: "23 março 2019". Queria saber se tem alguma forma de converter isso em um objeto Date.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui usando a lib `intl` do dart desta forma:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';


///Pega string no formato "23 março 2019" e adiciona os "de" ficando: "23 de março de ///2019"

String strDate = splitted[0];
        var fullDate = strDate
            .split(" ")
            .map((s) => " de " + s)
            .join()
            .trim()
            .split(' ')
            .skip(1)
            .join(' ');

initializeDateFormatting("pt_BR", null).then((_) {
          DateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
          var d = DateFormat.yMMMMd("pt_BR").parse(fullDate);
          print('date: ${d}');
        });
```